js: Number() округляет число
Функция Number округляет некоторые числа. Снизу пример. Как в этом случае лучше преобразовать value к числу?
const value = "9999999999999999.00"
const valueNumber = Number(value) // valueNumber равно 10 000 000 000 000 000 


А само value проверяли, там ещё потери точности не было? Если это float, то уже там могло что-то потеряться.

речь про браузер или какую-то еще среду?

Число ожидается целое или дробное?

@Grundy , CrazyElf
Браузер, да. Значение приходит с бэка, как string, при чем может прийти с двумя (не больше) числами после запятой, мне необходимо перевести строку в число. Соответсвенно нужно, чтобы преобразовывалась таким образом:
"9999999999.00" => 9999999999;
"100.50" => 100.5

Если бы приходили только целые числа, можно было воспользоваться встроенным типом BigInt - но так как могут быть и дробные - придется использовать стороннюю библиотеку

Так а что вы дальше с этими числами делаете? Может тупо запоминать, где точка была, а дальше работать как с целыми, как бы домножив до целого? )

Для работы с большими числами могу посоветовать библиотеку bignumber.js


const value = BigNumber("9999999999999999.0254");

console.log('Initial:', value); // Initial: "9999999999999999.0254"
console.log('Additional:', value.plus(2)); // Additional: "10000000000000001.0254"
console.log('Multiplied:', value.multipliedBy(2)); // Multiplied: "19999999999999998.0508"
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js@9.1.2/bignumber.min.js"></script>




Я ба на всякий случай привел вариант с дробной частью (не нулями).

@OliverPatterson добавил, спасибо за замечание!

Но теперь комментарии к коду не являются истинными)
